# Android webview load local javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am trying to load a javascript file stored on the device via html file which is loaded via a webview but never seems to load. I have tried using direct url's like you normally would in html and have also tried:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/www/js/jsfile.js"/>`

JavaScript is enabled on the webview settings too and works fine if I have it on a server.

Thanks if anyone can help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hi actually I thing you should call directly the js file because you are calling it from the browser which considers the asset folder being its root folder. You should use the "file:///" prefix when calling from java code. Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="www/js/jsfile.js"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loadDataWithBaseURL`.

Put all your javascript under an `assets` folder and give js file path relative to the assets directory in your script tag (in the html). Don't put a slash in the beginning of src.

Read the html into a string (`htmlStr`) and then load it in the webview as mentioned below.

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlStr, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

It has worked for me.