# inject javascript file in every webpage loaded in android's webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, inject

Is it possible to inject a javascript file (located in the asset folder) to be included every time a page is loaded in android webview.

Android version: ICS 4.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this:

webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("javascript:(alert())");

Comment: Thanks EMODE but this does not answer my question.

Comment: You can read the JS and load it as html webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlStr, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533207/android-webview-load-local-javascript

Comment: Do you know exactly what this means? "Read the html into a string (htmlStr)"

Comment: Loads the given data into this WebView, using baseUrl as the base URL for the content. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414312/android-webview-javascript-from-assets

Comment: Answer 2 has enough detail to get you going