# WebServer on Android

Tags: android, delphi

I have a website, a set of HTML, JS, and CSS files, all this successfully works under Apache Cordova via WebView on Android.

I want to run it on Delphi, via `TWebBrowser`, but if I open `index.hml` via `file://` then JS scripts will not get access to local files. Actually, the same thing happens on a PC, too.

I see the solution as follows: raise your HTTP server and connect to it from `TWebBrowser`. If my idea is correct, the actual question is: What is the reason to raise the WebServer for Android?

I am using Delphi 10.3 CE.

Comment: Are you asking how to make a webserver in Delphi?

Comment: Yes, in Delphi under Android.

Comment: Why would you want a webserver on an Android device?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533207/android-webview-load-local-javascript